# rePass negative number as ids in web api rest service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have created a rest API using Microsoft web api. I use negative numbers to do some business logic.

When I pass positive numbers to **GET** calls, the api returns proper response. However when I pass negative number as Id, API ignores it and return all the data.

How can I force to treat negative numbers as valid?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
[RoutePrefix("Somethings")]
public class SomethingsController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{Id:int}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponse GetSomethings(int id)
    {
        //Do Business logic
        return response;
    }

}



http://localhost/Somethings/-1 GET will hit GetSomethings method.
```

I am sure this will work for negative numbers.